# How can I add values to a list-method or deal with it in general?

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

I came across a predefined method which has a List<int> as return value:

```
public static List<int> FindMultiples(int integer, int limit){}
```

When I tried to add values to it with FindMultiples.Add(), it wouldn't compile, saying "...FindMultiples(int,int) is a method, which is not valid in the given context."

I expected the list to take the values I tried to add inside an if-statement, but it wouldn't.

```
public static List<int> FindMultiples(int integer, int limit)
            {
                int _integer = integer;
                int _limit = limit;
                
                FindMultiples(4, 20);
                
                if (FindMultiples.Count <= limit)
                {
                    FindMultiples.Add(integer * 1);
                    FindMultiples.Add(integer * 2);
                    FindMultiples.Add(integer * 3);
                    FindMultiples.Add(integer * 4);
                    FindMultiples.Add(integer * 5);
                }

                return FindMultiples();
            }
```

I'm stumped right now. Thanks in advance for helping a beginner!

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to change the internal code of the FindMultiples method or are you just trying to use a FindMultiple method?

Comment: What you've done there is overflow the stack. You're recursively calling your method.
Create a `var list = new List<int>()`, add your variables to that and then `return list`

Comment: Did you mean `public static List<int> FindMultiples(int integer, int limit) => Enumerable.Range(1, limit).Select(i => i* integer).ToList()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a `List<int>` in which you can perform `Add` operation & then return the list. You were adding values in  `FindMultiples()` which is a method not a collection.

```
    public static List<int> FindMultiples(int integer, int limit)
        {
            
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();

            
            if (lst.Count <= limit)
            {
                lst.Add(integer * 1);
                lst.Add(integer * 2);
                lst.Add(integer * 3);
                lst.Add(integer * 4);
                lst.Add(integer * 5);
            }

            return lst ;
        }
```